# How to generate multiple pandas dataframe from ordereddict?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Ordered Dictionary, where the keys are the worksheet names, and the values contain the the worksheet items. Thus, the question: How do I use each of the keys and convert to an individual dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
powerbipath = 'PowerBI_Ingestion.xlsx' dfs = pd.read_excel(powerbipath, None)

values=[] for idx, eachdf in enumerate(dfs):
    eachdf=dfs[eachdf]
    new_list1.append(eachdf)
    eachdf = pd.DataFrame(new_list1[idx])
```

Examples I have seen only show how to convert from an ordered dictionary to 1 pandas dataframe. I want to convert to multiple dataframes. Thus, if there are 5 keys, there will be 5 dataframes.

Comment: Hey Brian, Please provide a sample of what your dictionary looks like

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this, (Assuming your dictionary looks like 'd') :

```
d = {'first': [1, 2], 'second': [3, 4]}
for i in d:
  df = pd.DataFrame(d.get(i), columns=[i])
  print(df)
```

Output looks like :

```
   first
0      1
1      2
   second
0       3
1       4
```

Comment: @BrianBeing would you mind validating the answer if it was useful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic answer using one of [these ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742588/pandas-split-dataframe-by-column-value)

```
keys = df["key_column"].unique
df_array = {}
for k in keys : 
   df_array[k] = dfs[dfs['key_column'] == k]
```

There might be more efficient way to do it though.