# How to split a column with contains a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe need to split the column if `_` comes

```
Name = [('Hello'),
      ('Spider'),
      ('Captain'),
      ('Superman'),
       ('Hello_1'),
       ('Superman_1')]
dfName = pd.DataFrame(Name, columns=['Name'])
```

My Out

```
    Name
0   Hello
1   Spider
2   Captain
3   Superman
4   Hello_1
5   Superman_1
```

Expected Out

df1

```
    Name      
0   Hello
1   Spider
2   Captain
3   Superman
```

df2

```
    Name_
0   Hello_1
1   Superman_1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split DataFrame by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742588/pandas-split-dataframe-by-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask and filter by inverting mask for not contains with `~` for `df1` and without for `df2` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default `RangeIndex`:

```
m = dfName['Name'].str.contains('_')

#is sample data .reset_index(drop=True) not necessary, added for general solution
df1 = dfName[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
       Name
0     Hello
1    Spider
2   Captain
3  Superman

df2 = dfName[m].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
         Name
0     Hello_1
1  Superman_1
```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to split your first list into two sub lists first:

```
>>> name = 'Hello Spider Captain Superman Hello_1 Superman_1'.split()
>>> name
['Hello', 'Spider', 'Captain', 'Superman', 'Hello_1', 'Superman_1']
>>> col1 = [n for n in name if '_' not in n]
>>> col2 = [n for n in name if '_' in n]
>>> col1
['Hello', 'Spider', 'Captain', 'Superman']
>>> col2
['Hello_1', 'Superman_1']
>>>
```

Note: per convention variables should be lower case, to distinguish them from classes.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to split your data frame:

```
df1 = dfName[~dfName["Name"].str.contains('_1', na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = dfName[dfName["Name"].str.contains('_1', na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

the output of df1:

```
Name
0   Hello
1   Spider
2   Captain
3   Superman
```

the output of df2:

```
    Name
0   Hello_1
1   Superman_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfnamewithout_regex = dfName[~dfName['Name'].str.contains('_')]
dfnamewithout_regex
    Name
0   Hello
1   Spider
2   Captain
3   Superman

dfnamewith_regex = dfName[dfName['Name'].str.contains('_')]
dfnamewith_regex
Name
4   Hello_1
5   Superman_1
```

If you want to drop the index, add .reset_index(drop=True)