# how to split a series in pandas based on another

Tags: python, pandas, filesplitting

I have two series in python pandas.

One from values within a file called `values.csv`. It looks like this:

```
time, value
0, 10312435
9, 45924523
11, 43423434
20, 42343552
...
```

Another one is called `breaks.csv` and it looks like this:

```
time
5
18
...
```

**Problem**: I would like to split the `values.csv` into separate frames based on the values in `breaks.csv`.

In the example above the first breakpoint would be `5`, resulting in a file or set containing all entries within `time \in [0, 5]`, therefore only the value `0, 10312435`. The second breakpoint is `18`, therefore the second batch of values should be within `(5, 18]` i.e. `9, 45924523` and `11, 43423434` and so forth.

Is something like this possible in pandas (or maybe some other easy-to-use python package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following, based on [Pandas split DataFrame by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742588/pandas-split-dataframe-by-column-value)

```
sim_dist_right = pandas.read_csv('sim/dist_right.csv', comment='#')
sim_round_indicator = pandas.read_csv('sim/round_indicator.csv', comment='#')

round_list = []
for index, row in sim_round_indicator.iterrows():
    print("splitting at " + str(row['time']))
    df_sep = sim_dist_right[sim_dist_right['time'] < row['time']]
    
    round_list.append(df_sep)
    print("separated a batch of " + str(len(df_sep)) + " elements")
    
    df_over = sim_dist_right[sim_dist_right['time'] >= row['time']]
    print(str(len(df_over)) + " elements over")
    
    sim_dist_right = df_over
    
print("splitted values into " + str(len(round_list)) + " batches")
```

Comment: Use `.iterrows()` can work well, but not very efficiently. You can try `pd.cut` as above.

Answer (score 2):

You can first form bins from `breaks.time` and then assign categories to `values.time` with these bins using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
import numpy as np

# intervals to fall into
bins = [-np.inf, *breaks.time, +np.inf]

# distinct labels of 0..N-1
labels = np.arange(len(bins) - 1)

# form a new column in `values` with assigned categories
values["cats"] = pd.cut(values.time, bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

At this point `values` looks like:

```
>>> values

   time     value cats
0     0  10312435    0
1     9  45924523    1
2    11  43423434    1
3    20  42343552    2
```

Now we can group by `cats` and, for example, form a list of dataframes:

```
# no need for `cats` column anymore, so we drop it when putting in
frames_list = [frame.drop(columns="cats")
               for _, frame in values.groupby("cats")[["time", "value"]]]
```

We can access the frames as

```
>>> frames_list[0]

   time     value
0     0  10312435


>>> frames_list[1]

   time     value
1     9  45924523
2    11  43423434

>>> frames_list[2]

   time     value
3    20  42343552
```