# splitting dataframe into two subsets by boolean condition in one-liner

Tags: python, pandas

is there a way we can use when we apply a condition on a `df` and get two return values: one fulfilling the condition and the second with remaining part?

`df_with_condition, df_without_condition = df.[some conditional actions]`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the splitting command into two parts:

```
df_with_condition = df.[some conditional actions]
df_without_condition = df.[~(some conditional actions)]
```

Comment: i am familiar with this way of splitting. i am just curious if there's way to do it by one operation

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742588/pandas-split-dataframe-by-column-value. You could use the answer that uses mask.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about performing the boolean splitting task in a single line, you can use a generator expression with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df_false, df_true = (g for k,g in df.groupby(boolean_condition))
```

If you want the true condition first, invert the boolean with `~`:

```
df_true, df_false = (g for k,g in df.groupby(~boolean_condition))
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,0,1], 'B': list('ABCDE')})

# split by A<1 / A≥1
df1, df2 = (g for k,g in df.groupby(df['A'].ge(1)))

print(df1)
print('---')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  0  A
3  0  D
---
   A  B
1  1  B
2  2  C
4  1  E
```